# Is installing Magento through Softaculous considered a composer install?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.2

Obviously, this is not a repo install from Github.  And although this may be a very simple question, there is nothing that I found that explicitly states what type of install it is.

I installed through Softaculous, whether it's frowned upon or not.  I did not use composer as it was done through CPANEL and completed through the web app.  But when I research problems, solutions, etc. there are always only 2 methods for everything; a composer install, or a github repo install.  Which one of these methods does a Softaculous install fall under.  To state the obvious, extending files, along with folder architecture, are affected by the type of install.

Thanks in advance, and apologies for a newb question.